# Atomic Design: should a wrapper be an atom if it's not reusable?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, atomic-design

In our company we are using [Atomic Design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) for our design system (made with React and with Styled Components as our styling solution), in order to break down our UI into atoms, molecules and organisms

I have a doubt regarding when an atom should be classified as an atom or if it should be inside its parent domain.

You can see an example of this type of composition in this [Material UI Card](https://codesandbox.io/s/py3x3?file=/demo.js) example (which does not use atomic design, but you can get the idea anyway).

So, imagine the following example, you have a Card Atom (since it's only a wrapper that returns a styled HTML tag with children):

```
const Card = ({children}) => <StyledWrapper>{children}</StyledWrapper>
```

There are also defined some children to go along with the `Card`, such as `CardHeader`, `CardBody` and `CardFooter`, all of them optional styled wrappers and they are passed as children if necessary.

So, which would be the right approach in this example?

- `CardHeader`, `CardBody` and `CardFooter` should be classified as atoms, outside the `Card` domain (meaning it's folder)

```
-- atoms
  -- Card
  -- CardHeader
  -- CardBody
  -- CardFooter
```

- `CardHeader`, `CardBody` and `CardFooter` should be placed inside the `Card` domain since they are not reusable (meaning they are designed to be used only with the `Card` atom), and should be exported there alongside `Card`, so the only atom in this example would be `Card`

```
-- atoms
  -- Card
    -- CardHeader
    -- CardBody
    -- CardFooter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: The Latter.

```
-- atoms
  -- Card
    -- CardHeader
    -- CardBody
    -- CardFooter
```

As you said, `CardHeader`, `CardBody` are not reusable outside of `Card` domain. Therefore, it will not make sense to put these sub-components on the same level as a Card. Pro Tip: You can encapsulate these sub-components so they are exported under Card. E.g. `Card.Header`, `Card.Body` etc to make things more obvious.

Another point that may help you: in my projects, I do not assume Card to be an atom, but a molecule. Atoms are the building blocks. A Card is a collection of smaller building blocks like Text, Images and Buttons. Hence, it makes more sense as a molecule.

Comment: So, from your suggestion, it should be like this:
`atoms = { CardHeader, CardBody, CardFooter }` and `molecules = { Card }`

Comment: @ilumin Not exactly. Atoms are simplest building blocks like Text and Buttons that go in card. CardHeader you can think of as slots that can contain one or more atoms. These slots together can still make up a molecule like a card. And when you have multiple cards, it can make an organism, a card carousel or card row.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to understand, you mean, `Card` is a molecule that has a slot `CardHeader` right?

Comment: Correct, Yes thats true